# Javascript String to Regex without Escaping

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a question regarding regular expressions in nodejs/javascript.

What I am trying to achieve is to convert a regex (loaded from a database as a string) without any escaping to a RegExp object in js.

```
var regex       = /Apache\/([0-9\.]+) \(([a-zA-Z ]+)\) (.+)/;
var regexString = '/Apache\/([0-9\.]+) \(([a-zA-Z ]+)\) (.+)/';

var str = 'Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny18';

var match = str.match(regex);
var match2 = str.match(new RegExp(regexString));
console.log(match);
console.log(match2);
```

That's what I tried so far. But as you can see it won't match if the string gets escaped...
My output:

```
[ 'Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny18',
  '2.2.9',
  'Debian',
  'PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny18',
  index: 0,
  input: 'Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny18' ]
null
```

Am I missing something simple? If not any suggestions for me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two bounding `/` are not supposed to be present when used in the string argument of `new RegExp()`.

Also, when you would write the string as a literal (which I understand is not really your case, since you get the string from the DB), you need to escape any backslashes in that literal to `\\`:

```js
var regex       = /Apache\/([0-9\.]+) \(([a-zA-Z ]+)\) (.+)/;
var regexString = 'Apache\/([0-9\.]+) \\(([a-zA-Z ]+)\\) (.+)';

var str = 'Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny18';

var match = str.match(regex);
var match2 = str.match(new RegExp(regexString));
console.log(match);
console.log(match2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```